# How to implement Circuit_macros on windows, with TexLive

Tags: packages, texlive, windows, circuitikz

I'm  a Windows 7 user new to LaTeX, and I've gotten pretty decent at it rather quickly. I started with MiKTeX and then switched to TeX Live. As an electrical engineering undergraduate, I want to use `circuit_macros`. But despite my lengthy searches I can't seem to find a way to get the packages, or I guess they are m4 files, into TeX Live so I can mess around with it for writing homework. I have already downloaded the latest `circuit_macros` files. I should mention that I already tried downloading the package with the command

```
tlmgr install circuit_macros
```

and I keep getting an error called as:

```
package circuit_macros not present in package repository
```

I would be immensely appreciative if someone could point me in th right direction.

I would also settle with having to reinstall MiKTeX if it yields a simpler solution to my problem.

Comment: `circuit_macros` is in neither the miktex  nor the tl repos, so if you need it, you've to install it, and the supporting `m4` and `pic` processors (at least).  i expect such exist, but have never looked for them for windoze.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at http://staff.ee.sun.ac.za/pjrandewijk/wiki/index.php/M4_Circuit_Macros_-_Installation

There is a guide to windows 7 and download links to m4 and DPIC compatible versions.

BTW at https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~aplevich/Circuit_macros/ you can download The latest release.