# Properly installing circuit_macros on a Windows PC

Tags: circuits, engineering

I want to use `circuit_macros`, a tool for creating circuit diagrams  using M4 macros written by Dwight Aplevich. I am using Windows and face problems since most of the avalaible documentation are for UNIX and GNU/Linux users.

I am using Miktex 2.9 with Texmaker 5.0.2 on Windows 8.1. Following the installation instructions, here is what I have done so far:

1. **Downloaded the .exe files of dpic (pic interpreter) from**
   [https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~aplevich/dpic/Windows/index.html](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/%7Eaplevich/dpic/Windows/index.html)
   I've put the two executables files `dpic.exe` and `m4.exe` inside a newly-created folder at: `C:\dpic`.
   Then I added do the **Path** variable the above-mentioned folder from the "View Advanced System Settings" menu, so that I can execute these programs regardless of the directory inside which I am.
2. **Downloaded and installed a m4 macro interpreter.**
   Still according to Aplevich's instructions on the repository, one may download a program from the sourceforge website at:
   http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/m4.htm
3. **Downloaded and unzipped the circuit_macros distribution from CTAN**
4. **Decided where to install the .m4 library files**
   I created the localtexmf folder at `C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\circuit_macros` and copied the downloaded unzipped files of the distribution to the target folder.
5. **Copied boxdims.sty from the top distribution directory to where LaTeX will find it**
   In my case, I pasted it to newly-created folder called "boxdims" at:
   `C:\Users\billyandriam\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX2.9\miktex\tex\latex\boxdims\`.

   After that, I opened the MikTex console and from the upper-left menus, I clicked on Tasks>Refresh file name database.
6. **Defined the environment variable M4PATH to point to the installation
   directory determined in Step number 4.**
   In the Control Panel at "View Advanced System Settings", I created a new environment variable called **M4PATH** and attributed as its value the following directory: `C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\circuit_macros\`.

Now, my installation works with some limitations. When I have a .m4 file and run the appropriate command, the .m4 file converts to .tex **with no errors**. So, from Windows's command prompt, this is the command I used to create the "filename.tex" file (At the beginning, I put `include(pgf.m4)` at the first line of the .m4 because it has to generate a Tikz picture):

> **m4 filename.m4 | dpic -g > filename.tex**

Yet, I cannot invoke m4 and dpic from a latex document directly.
As an illustration, let us consider the following latex code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\mtotex[2]{\immediate\write18{m4 #2.m4 | dpic -#1 > #2.tex}}

\begin{document}
\mtotex{g}{filename} %This line should create filename.tex from filename.m4
\input{filename.tex}
\end{document}
```

For some reasons, typesetting the above MWE returns an error. Did I miss something?

Comment: [Crosspost](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=32189&p=107953#p107952)

Comment: @Johannes_B Please go ahead and delete my post on latex.org forum, it was a clumsy move from me.

Comment: @mandresybilly Maybe "https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156794/how-to-implement-circuit-macros-on-windows-with-texlive/157055#157055" may be a start point?

Comment: @jotagah Thank you for the advice.One link on the accepted answer seems to have an installation guide but unfortunately, that link is no more working now.

Comment: \immediate\write needs --shell-escape as option, that means you need to call `latex --shell-escape document`. Beside this: better move boxdims.sty to your localtexmf (in `C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\circuit_macros`), I would also put the m4 files there and change the environment variable accordingly.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I quite didn't understand what you meant by the option needed by \immediate\write. The MWE I used in the question was just an example I copied from the `cicruit_macros`'s most [recent manual](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~aplevich/Circuit_macros/CMman.pdf) on page 4. Please feel free to open a chat for better explanation.

Comment: latex will not run external programs (for security reasons) unless you allow them by adding the option --shell-escape. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/236648/2388 for how to add it in texmaker.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Oh! Thanks a million for that graphic explanation. It works now! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LaTeX will not run external applications (for security reasons) unless you allow this by using the option `--shell-escape`.

`\immediate\write18{...}` is such a call to an external application.

See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/236648/2388 how to add the option to the texmaker call.

I would also suggest to move boxdims.sty and the m4 files to your localtexmf in `C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\circuit_macros`

If not done yet add `C:\localtexmf` to the `TEXMF root directories` in MikTeX Console under the buttons `Settings>Directories>(add the localtexmf path)` or refresh the FNDB with the entry in the tasks menu.

Comment: My last question is why is it better practice to move boxdims.sty to `C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\circuit_macros` and not inside the MikTex folders? And after updating the environment variable **M4PATH** to the new directory, should I also add `C:\localtexmf`  to the **TEXMF root directories** in Miktex under the buttons **Settings>Directories>**_add the localtexmf path_ for it to work?

Comment: Leave the main miktex directory alone. At first you can break things, and at second you can loose things if you have to reinstall miktex. And yes, you should add localtexmf as a new root.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That makes sense. Ok got it. I will edit your answer for completeness :).

Answer (score 1):

Although the question has already been answered, other users finding a simple way to use circuit-macros into LaTeX may find useful [the PyCirkuit tool](https://github.com/orestesmas/pycirkuit), which works on GNU/Linux, Mac and windows systems.